# How to test if a string is partialy contained in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the list:

```
list1 = ['tom.frank.phillips','jimmy.fund.roberts','markus.shane.sherman','glen.carl.smith']
```

I am trying to test if the following names are contained anywhere in this list:

```
nameslist = ['shane', 'frank', 'dale', 'roberts', 'smith', 'tony']
```

If they are not contained anywhere in the original list, then I want to print the name.

I have tried:

```
for name in nameslist:
    if name not in list1:
        print(name)
```

But when I do this, all of the names get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those names is an element of `list1`.  You need to check to see whether the name is a sub-string of any *element* of `list1`.

```
if not any(name in full_name for full_name in list1):
    print(name)
```

Another way is to simply concatenate all of your long names; then use `in` on that single string:

```
all_names = ' '.join(list1)
for name in names list:
    if not name in all_names:
        print(name)
```